# Evidence for Nature works under direction of God?

Tags: theology, existence-of-god

I have read from somewhere[¹](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/9/10/) and it sounds very right, that Nature works under supervision of God.

However problem with this, may be that it seems unfalsifiable. What would be nature like with supervision of God and without supervision of God?

For it, this question that is there any phenomenon, or anything in nature that can only explainable if Nature works under direction of God?

What would constitute evidence for it?

For example, design of DNA, fine tuning of universe, emergence, chaotic unpredictability or like it

Comment: It is an old philosophical discussion; see [Cosmological argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_argument).

Comment: We should first define "God" unambiguously. If it's the same designer who put a blind spot in the middle of my eyes, I sure hope they didn't also design my DNA (alas, the numerous copy errors and congenital defects DNA causes bear the trademark of their incompetence...)

Comment: you gotta define "supervision" too.